# How to create HTML element with lang attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, lang

I want to create a new element with a `lang` attribute.

Can I do that as a one-liner ? If not what is the shortest method ?

Comment: As long as you place the `;` properly in most case you can write JS in one line...

Comment: not what I meant by one-liner, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with the `Firebug` console, I found that [`createElement()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-2141741547) return an [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-745549614) object which has a [`lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.lang).

So you can use:

### `lang` attribute

```
var elt = document.createElement("i");
elt.lang = 'fr';
```

### [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) method

```
var elt = document.createElement("i");
elt.setAttribute('lang','fr');
```

Answer (score 5):

The shortest you can do is a two-liner:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.lang = 'en';
```

Comment: Here is a non-workable exemple: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18485948/802365, see my answer for a more complete solution.

Comment: @EdouardLopez: How are you testing it? The `lang` property should work.

Comment: The issue on the related question was a namespace issue

Answer (score 2):

As [Blender says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18482151/157247), you have to have two statements (which would traditionally be written in two lines).

You can, of course, give yourself a helper function to do it in one:

```
function createElement(type, props) {
    var key;
    var elm = document.createElement(type);
    if (props) {
        for (key in props) {
            elm[key] = props[key];
        }
    }
    return elm;
}
```

Usage:

```
var newSpan = createElement("span", {lang: "en"});
```

Comment: Good one for reusability, but I don't need it in this case.