# elt.lang = 'fr' not working

Tags: javascript, attributes, firefox-addon, lang

I work in the **context of a Firefox extension**.

### Issue

I'm trying to create a new element with a specific `lang` attribute. I tried the method  `elt.lang = 'zh'` given in [How to create HTML element with lang attribute in JavaSript?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) doens't work. The element is created but without the `lang` attribute.

### Not working as expected code

```
var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
  var zh = document.createElement("i");
    zh.textContent = symbol;
    zh.lang= "zh-cmn"; // <-- -- -- -- -- -- --
  var srcText = document.createTextNode('blablabla');
wrapper.appendChild(zh);
wrapper.appendChild(srcText);
```

### Working as expected code

However when I use the [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) method it works fine:

```
zh.setAttribute('lang','zh');
```

Why the `elt.lang`/dot-notation approach not working ?

Comment: I made [my own test case](http://jsbin.com/asaDoY/1/edit), inspected the generated element in a DOM Inspector and saw the lang attribute rendered as expected. I could not reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you test in the context of a Firefox extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

The problem was related to the environment (i.e. an extension). I was in a XUL context so using [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) create a XUL element which don't have a `lang` attribute.

So to fix problem and other (no way to select inserted text), I had to **force the XHTML namespace** with [`createElementNS(ns, elt)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS).

### Code

```
var nsXHTML = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
var wrapper = document.createElementNS(nsXHTML, "span");
var zh = document.createElementNS(nsXHTML, "i");
zh.lang= "zh-cmn";
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all possible HTML attributes are reflected as javascript setters / getters. For instance, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node definitely lists textContent, but not `lang`. I would suggest *always* using setAttribute / getAttribute, except for possibly the most basic attributes such as "src" or "href".

Comment: It's present in the HTMLDom specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59132807 which is an specification of DOM